# SQL - CASE WHEN THEN ELSE DO Noting

Tags: sql, case

I have written the following, however at the ** ** after 16 below I would like to end the case statement by allowing all other results to return as they originally were, do nothing - instead of returning null.

EG raw data

```
1
2
3
4
7
10
16
EXAMPLE1
EXAMPLE2
EXAMPLE3
```

Results I would get with Code Below

```
User Security ID
User Name
Full Name
State
Windows Security ID
License Type
Application ID
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Results I want

```
User Security ID
User Name
Full Name
State
Windows Security ID
License Type
Application ID
EXAMPLE1
EXAMPLE2
EXAMPLE3
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
 
[Date and Time] as [Date],
[User ID] as [User Performing Change],
[Type of Change],
CASE [Field No_]

WHEN 1 THEN 'User Security ID'
WHEN 2 THEN 'User Name'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Full Name'
WHEN 4 THEN 'State'
WHEN 7 THEN 'Windows Security ID'
WHEN 10 THEN 'License Type'
**WHEN 16 THEN 'Application ID'

END as [Data],**
[Old Value],
[New Value],
[Record ID]
FROM [DB].[dbo].[TABLE$Change Log Entry]
where [Table No_] = 20000
order by [Field No_]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `else`:

```
CASE [Field No_]
    WHEN '1'  THEN 'User Security ID'
    WHEN '2'  THEN 'User Name'
    WHEN '3'  THEN 'Full Name'
    WHEN '4'  THEN 'State'
    WHEN '7'  THEN 'Windows Security ID'
    WHEN '10' THEN 'License Type'
    WHEN '16' THEN 'Application ID'
    ELSE [Field No_]
END as [Data]
```

Note that I changed the values that are being compared from literal numbers to literal strings, since it appears that your column is of a string datatype.

**Edit**

If your column is of a numeric datatype, then:

```
CASE [Field No_]
    WHEN  1 THEN 'User Security ID'
    WHEN  2 THEN 'User Name'
    WHEN  3 THEN 'Full Name'
    WHEN  4 THEN 'State'
    WHEN  7 THEN 'Windows Security ID'
    WHEN 10 THEN 'License Type'
    WHEN 16 THEN 'Application ID'
    ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), [Field No_])
END as [Data]
```

Comment: I now seem to face the following error:
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'User Security ID' to data type int.

Comment: @ChristopherBrogan: ok, so you have an integer column. See my edit.